# The conditions for a function to be quasi-concave

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $g(x)$ is increasing convex, $c(x)$is increasing convex, $e(x)$ is increasing concave, and $h(x)$ is increasing concave.

If I want to show function $$f(x)=x+e(x)h(x)-c(e(x))-g(x)$$ is quasi-concave, instead of directly assuming $f(x)$ is quasi-concave, are there any other assumptions I could make on functions $h(x), g(x), c(x),$ and $e(x)$ to let $f(x)$ be quasi-concave?

Comment: Should $u(x)$ be $f(x)$?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for pointing out!

Comment: What does "quasi-concave" mean? It would be better to add more details on this definition in the main question.